# input function inside a nested function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is strange. I have searched this problem, but I didn't find any similar question. The following code in Python 3.X is the simplest model that I can explain.

```
def is_correct(function,wait_sec=0.5):
    while True:
        output = function
        is_correct = input('Is the input correct(y(Enter)/n)?')
        time.sleep(1)
        if is_correct.lower() in ['','y','yes']:
            clear_output()
            time.sleep(wait_sec)
            return output
        clear_output()
        time.sleep(wait_sec)

def whileloop(fun):
    while True:
        fun
def INPUT():
    result=input('...')

def hello_world():
    print('hello world')

def forloop(fun):
    for i in range(3):
        fun
```

Thus, when I run forloop(INPUT()), it only let me input two times. when I run whileloop(INPUT()), I got one input and then an infinite loop. Most strangely, when I run is_correct(hello_world), it only print 'hello world' once.

Any idea?

Comment: `output = function`, and never changes, so if `output = True` it will run forever.

Comment: Also,  what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I have different input modules, and after each input I ask user if the input is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `()` when using argument `fun` or `function` inside functions,
And when you call the functions, you should pass the argument without `()` like `forloop(INPUT)` and `whileloop(INPUT)`

```
def is_correct(function,wait_sec=0.5):
    while True:
        output = function()
        is_correct = input('Is the input correct(y(Enter)/n)?')
        #time.sleep(1)
        if is_correct.lower() in ['','y','yes']:
            #clear_output()
            #time.sleep(wait_sec)
            return output
        #clear_output()
        #time.sleep(wait_sec)

def whileloop(fun):
    while True:
        fun()
def INPUT():
    result=input('...')

def hello_world():
    print('hello world')

def forloop(fun):
    for i in range(3):
        fun()

forloop(INPUT)
```

Comment: Thanks! But this is not what I want to achieve. Basically, I have input_1(), input_2(), and input_3(), and the "function" will be either one of them.

Comment: @彭俊文 I just change the syntax of the code to make it work, you can still pass input_1(), input_2(), and input_3() to as argument, like `forloop(input_1)`, `whileloop(input_2)`, `is_correct(input_3)`

Comment: @彭俊文 You may mark my answer as accepted if you find it useful. Have a nice day.